# setTimeOut causing function to trigger before button is clicked

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm just in the middle of a javascript course and am playing around with a very basic project whereby I need to generate random shapes (just squares and circles) which should appear in random positions on the page. The first shape needs to appear after a random delay once a start button is clicked.

Originally I was drawing the shapes on a canvas but as the drawn shapes need to be clickable later for the project and as I only need to generate squares and circles, I've settled on just using divs which vary in shape, size and position. I have the shapes appearing just fine once the button is clicked but I'm struggling to add in the delay on the function. This is my code without the delay:

```
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <div id="shape"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function generateRandomShape() {
      var randomColor = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple"];
      var radiusOptions = ["50%", ""]
      document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = randomColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length)];
      document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = radiusOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * radiusOptions.length)];
      document.getElementById("shape").style.height = Math.random() * 500;
      document.getElementById("shape").style.width = document.getElementById("shape").style.height;
      document.getElementById("shape").style.marginLeft = Math.random() * 1000;
      document.getElementById("shape").style.marginTop = Math.random() * 400;
    };

    document.getElementById("start").onclick = generateRandomShape;

  </script>
```

I tried modifying the onclick call as follows:

```
        document.getElementById("start").onclick = setTimeOut(generateRandomShape,2000);
```

But now the function triggers after 2 secs without the button being clicked (I'll be adding in the random element to the time delay using Math.random once I get this working!). Can't work out the logic as to why this is triggering prior to the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = setTimeOut(generateRandomShape,2000);
```

Causes the `setTimout` function to run immediately because as soon as it is encountered, the function is executed and the return value (if any) is what gets assigned to the `onclick` property.

Change the line to:

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){setTimeout(generateRandomShape,2000)};
```

So that the function that contains the `setTimeout` instruction gets stored in the `onclick` property and won't run until the `click` event happens. Also, you had mis-capitalized `setTimeout` as `setTimeOut`.

Also, you don't need `type=text/javascript` in your `script` tags.

Besides that, your function is not written to perform very well. You should only scan for an element one time instead of on each line of your code, like this:

```js
function generateRandomShape() {

  var randomColor = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple"];
  var radiusOptions = ["50%", ""]
  var shape = document.getElementById("shape");  // <-- Just scan for the element once
  
  shape.style.backgroundColor = randomColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length)];
  shape.style.borderRadius = radiusOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * radiusOptions.length)];
  shape.style.height = Math.random() * 500;
  shape.style.width = shape.style.height;
  shape.style.marginLeft = Math.random() * 1000;
  shape.style.marginTop = Math.random() * 400;
};

// It's better to use modern standards for event wiring (.addEventListener)
// instead of event properties (.onclick)
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click",function(){ 
  // You had mis-capitalized setTimeout as setTimeOut!
  setTimeout(generateRandomShape,2000)
});
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div id="shape">This is the shape element.</div>
```

Comment: awesome that's really helpful and super clear. Thanks a lot for your help!